# Tag friends in facebook post from application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to tag friends in a post created from my application?

I had seen somewhere that its not available with the facebook api..

please help me .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Read about it [on Open Graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/mention_tagging/)

Comment: Just to be clear: That’s for Open Graph actions. But for normal posts, it is not possible (any more).

Comment: Yes, but you’ll have to get that approved first; and you might most likely be required to provide the same kind of controls (overview over published “post” actions, mechanism to undo them, …) as for any other OG action … so it’s a little more complicated, then just “switching over” from a normal post to a custom “post” action …